# How to access UWP JS APIs in a UWP C# app?

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-c#

We have a bunch of JavaScript code that uses [UWP APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/) that was written for a UWP Javascript app (`.jsproj`). Now this app is rewritten as a UWP C# app.

The UWP APIs in C#, JS and C++ are similar enough, [see these examples for `ApplicationData.LocationSetting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings#examples), so migrating the code would not be that much of an effort - but it would still be work that has to be done.

Is there a way so that I do *not* have to rewrite all our JavaScript code in C# to be able to use it in our rewritten app? Can I somehow use the UWP JS APIs in a UWP C# app?

I was hoping I could use a simple [webview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view) to somehow access the APIs (my thinking was that the UWP JS app basically *is* just a webview), but in my testing I could not access them there.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. First you say that you're rewriting your JS app into C#. Then you're saying that you don't want to rewrite your JS code into C#. The UWP APIs can be called from both JS and C#. Can you give an example of a UWP API that works in JS and not in C#? You can find many examples of translations between JS and C# in [the UWP samples repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/). They call the same underlying UWP APIs.

Comment: I am asking about a way to use the JS code written against the UWP JS APIs in a UWP C# app (similar to how it is possible to use UWP C# APIs in a UWP JS app via a Windows Runtime Component in the other direction for example), instead of rewriting that JS code in C#.

Comment: Ah, I see. In the first two paragraphs, you mean "UWP APIs in the OS", but in the third paragraph, you mean "UWP APIs in my app". Which is a bit of a misnomer because those functions in your JS app aren't UWP APIs; they're just JS function. What you're really asking is "I have some functions written in JS, and I'd like to call them from C#." You could create a WebView, put your JS in that WebView, and then use `AddWebAllowedObject` to inject your C# objects into the WebView, and use `InvokeScriptAsync` to call a function and gather the result.

Comment: `AddWebAllowedObject` for `Windows.*` sounds like an idea, I will look into that. Thanks. (Yes, choosing the right words to describe this wasn't that easy - UWP JS seems to be almost gone from documentation already :/)

Answer (score 1):

Although I totally agree that JavaScript code looks similar to C# code. I'm afraid you cannot get what you want like your first post mentioned. The webview control is lightweight and I don't think it is possible for this control to include all required components for your js code to run.

If you've wrote some code in Windows Runtime Component before, like this doc [Walkthrough: Creating a Simple Windows Runtime component and calling it from JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript) mentioned, then you can reuse the Windows Runtime Component. But if you haven't done this, then I'm afraid you have to rewrite your code in C#.

Well, by the way, I believe you will find C# code is easy for you to write since there are more UWP C# demos then UWP JS demos.

Comment: Shame, I was hoping there was a bridge or API that I missed that could make UWP JS available in UWP C#. We do have a few WinRT components, but most of it was built "on the platform", so is pure JavaScript. (One reason for our migration is that UWP JS has been deprecated/abandoned, so I am very aware of UWP C# being better documented :))

Comment: @janpio Yep, There is no bridge. Right now PWA is recommend technology.

Comment: What about the two options listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#accessing-the-windows-runtime-in-webview? PWA is not nearly ready if you need to use native code.

Comment: @janpio Raymond is on the right track.  AddWebAllowedObject and InvokeScriptAsync is the right way for you. But as I have no idea what are wrote in your project, I cannot know which way is better for you from either rewrite the whole project in C# or directly use AddWebAllowedObject and webview. Anyway, you can give the AddWebAllowedObject a try first to see if it can already meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This never got a proper answer, but the correct answer is to use the now-deprecated JSRT apis. These can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Chakra-Samples/tree/master/Chakra%20Samples/JSRT%20Universal%20Windows%20Apps%20Hosting%20Samples), and an old blog post about them to provide some understanding can be found [here](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/18/using-chakra-for-scripting-applications-across-windows-10/).

Obviously this isn't as useful anymore with the deprecation of Spartan Edge, but still can be helpful when there's no alternative options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I could have _really_ needed to know about that 2 years ago :D

Comment: Yea sorry, I figured it might help someone else desperately trying to salvage an app.

Comment: No need to apologize, I love that you posted this now.